# After importing products from excel logging out

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, product-import

I import products from an excel file. After everything passes I do not get any errors. The table with catalog products looks like this:

[image]

I have hidden the names of the products, but all products have names. I run indexer-reindex and flush the cache. After I refresh the page the strangest thing happens. When I click on some of the new products that I've just imported it automatically logs me out and redirects me to the login screen for the admin panel. If I click on some of the old products that I've imported manually - I can go and edit the product as expected.

Anyone has any idea why ?

Comment: have you tried to clean catalog/product cache?

Comment: any error in the log?

Comment: I think I got it guys, for some reason the values for the default store for the name of the product got erased, I am investigating, I will post what I found as an answer, I think this is the problem - names are inserted for the second language, but not in the default store. No other reason, 10x for the fast replies.

Comment: Nope, was not that... I hav eno idea what is going on, no errors what so ever.